# How can I get the estimated power consumption of the app programmatically?

Tags: android, battery

can use `adb shell dumpsys battery` to get the power consumption, but cannot be obtained by code.
How can I get the power consumption of my app?

Answer (score 0):

There is no documented API to do that. System applications can access the information, but it's not very accurate on most of the devices.